# how can i add JavaScript code after once user key authenticated with the domain name

Tags: javascript

I want to create sale analytics and performance measurement crawler or tool. I want to create an application where people will register with their website domain name and I will provide the script with a key... something like the following

window.omnipredict_key = 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx';

I need to authenticate the key then my script will be included in that particular website and I am done and plan next to develop my script. The idea is about to crawl users activities.

How can I make this possible? I want to make it like CND anyone can copy and past with there keys and use my script. If the keys wrong I will put a message in the console

Comment: I'm unsure about what you're asking. You want to add a script to peoples website with a personalized key and then that script needs to verify that key before it does a thing?

Comment: of course. What you think is the best way to do it?

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me or there is nothing you people cant help and suggest solution?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad and really too high-level for SO but I try to give you some pointers here.

One way would be:

- You would need a database of sorts where you store access tokens
- You let your users include your script with the token (yes a CDN would be good here)
- In the script you check that the token exists
- Do your crawling or whatever your script does
- Send the result to the server with the token in the header
- On the server you check the token against your database and only if it exists and everything checks out you store the data for later consumption

Another way could be:

- You would need a database of sorts where you store access tokens
- You let the users include your script from a CDN with he token in the url
- You have the server check the token on request with the database
- You do the crawling
- You send the data to the server (again via token in header for auth)
- On the server you check the token against your database and only if it exists and everything checks out you store the data for later consumption

It all depends on what tech you got to your disposal etc...

Comment: your answer is 100% correct and thanks for your time... I know the above follow basically. But i dont know how i will include the script usinf CND (My own script) and make the authentication possible i need help with it please... how i will achieve..?
How i will include using javascript the script i want after authentication..? is there a example or best way to do it?

Comment: can you reply me please on it?

Comment: @QaisarMughal mate it's 6am where I am.. chill! And I can't help you further unless you share code.

Comment: ok np problem thank you... I need suggestion not i am stuck in an issue thanks :)